# compile single vue component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have created a vue project using `vue create myapp`. There I have created several components within:

```
src/components/MyFirst.vue
src/components/MySecond.vue
```

I have also adjusted my `vue.config.js` the following way:

```js
module.exports = {
  css: {
    extract: false,
  },
  configureWebpack: {
    optimization: {
      splitChunks: false
    },
    output: {
      filename: '[name].js',
      chunkFilename: '[name].js'
    }
  }
}
```

So that `yarn build` creates a single File `app.js`

Now I would like to use the components I defined there in a static HTML file:

```html
<html lang="de">
<head>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/app.js"></script>
    <title>MyPage<title>
</head>
<body>
    <my-comp></my-comp>
</body>
```

1. What do I have to do to achieve this?
2. Is there a way to compile it to one `js` file per component?

Comment: Import the components you created in the script section of the HTML page.
`import { componentName } from filePath`

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Vue CLI supports a [*library* target](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/build-targets.html#library), where you can register imported component definitions; or [*web component* target](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/build-targets.html#web-component), where components are automatically registered upon import (allowing you to drop in the component like in your example).

Edit the `build` NPM script in `package.json` to add the following parameters:

```js
// package.json
{
  "scripts": {
    "build": "vue-cli-service build --target wc --name my-component src/components/MyComponent.vue"
  }
}
```

The generated `dist/demo.html` shows example usage:

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
<script src="./my-component.js"></script>
<my-component></my-component>
```